# Google Maps Content Adding

Tags: google-maps, xhtml

I'm currently developing a website and part of it involves using Google Maps. I'd like for users of the site to be able to add markers with video/picture content. How would I go about giving users this ability?

Comment: How would the users specify the content?

Comment: They'd go to a part of the globe, create a marker, and put content in that marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, an infowindow can contain HTML.  So I'd say it comes down to just a few things:

1. Display a map
2. Have an event listener for a 'click' on the map.  This will trigger a function to add a new marker on the map.  Each marker should have it's own infowindow most likely (or you can use one, if you only want to display one at a time)
3. Prompt the user for content to add to the infowindow.  I assume you'd have a form with a textarea into which they enter HTML for displaying an image or video.  Unless you wanted to be more specific, e.g. only accepting URLs for certain sites (e.g. Youtube, Flickr etc).  And you could possibly even integrate with their APIs too.
4. Update the infowindow
5. Assuming you somehow want to save the marker and its content for future use, you'll need an AJAX call to be made when the marker is created, and when its content gets updated.  This should pass through I suppose details of the latlng of the marker, its content, and perhaps details of the user who created it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm reading tutorials and the APIs now (should've just done this in the first place), thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this php class](http://www.freakstyle.it/classes/gmapsv3/samples/sample11b.php) (There is many options)

Comment: sort of except that it doesn't really say anything about others adding markers